# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug' Cordova Gradle Ionic

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle

I just updated my cordova android to 7.1.0 to support the android 27 sdk to solve an issue where a plugin would not work with sdk 26.

I've tried changing the gradle distribution url in the GradleBuilder.js file and had no success.

**Edit:** I have tried invalidating the cache for gradle by opening android studio and using File>Invalidate Caches

**Edit 2:** The firebase plugin I wanted to solve the issue for appears to be part of the problem. Removing: cordova-plugin-firebase allows the app to be built with no issues. It also seems that after the plugin is added, I cannot simply remove it with: ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase

It gives this error:

```
missing file :: app/src/main
Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...

(node:11396) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Uh oh!
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\programs\myApp\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml'
```

**Edit 3:** It appears that the issue is potentially a conflict between the Firebase plugin and the Intercom plugin
https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase
https://github.com/intercom/intercom-cordova

I created a new ionic app and only added these two plugins, they ran fine with just one, but when both are installed the build will fail and provide this error:
    Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'. > java.io.IOException: Could not delete path 'C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug\www'.

**Edit 4:** Solved the mergeDebugAssets by updating node and npm. The test app built. When I tried adding other plugins from the original app, one of them reproduced the same original 'app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug' error. The plugin added is: 
https://github.com/ratson/cordova-plugin-admob-free
Removing the Intercom plugin and leaving the Firebase and Admob plugins together creates the app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug with a longer message.

Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with
>    arguments {--input C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\25.jar --output C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar
>   \debug\27.jar --input C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\10.jar --output C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desug
>   ar\debug\12.jar --input C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\68.jar --output C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\des
>   ugar\debug\37.jar --input C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\14.jar --output C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\d
>   esugar\debug\16.jar --input C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\12.jar --output C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms
>   \desugar\debug\14.jar --input C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\21.jar --output C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transfor
>   ms\desugar\debug\23.jar --input C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\18.jar --output C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transf
>   orms\desugar\debug\20.jar --input C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\62.jar --output C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\tran
>   sforms\desugar\debug\31.jar --input C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\16.jar --output C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\tr
>   ansforms\desugar\debug\18.jar --input C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\5.jar --output C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\t
>   ransforms\desugar\debug\7.jar --input C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\67.jar --output C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\
>   transforms\desugar\debug\36.jar --input C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\11.jar --output C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediate
>   s\transforms\desugar\debug\13.jar --input C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\1.jar --output C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediat
>   es\transforms\desugar\debug\3.jar --input C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\22.jar --output C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermedia
>   tes\transforms\desugar\debug\24.jar --input C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\72.jar --output C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermed
>   iates\transforms\desugar\debug\41.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build\intermediates\intermediate-jars\debug\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\and
>   roid\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\0.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\a
>   ndroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\1.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\2.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormPro
>   jects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\3.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\4.jar --classpath_entry C
>   :\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\5.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\deb
>   ug\6.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\7.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\tra
>   nsforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\8.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\9.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android
>   \app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\10.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\11.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProject
>   s\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\12.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\13.jar --classpath_entry C:\
>   Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\14.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debu
>   g\15.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\16.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\tr
>   ansforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\17.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\18.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\andr
>   oid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\19.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\20.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProj
>   ects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\21.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\22.jar --classpath_entry
>   C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\23.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\d
>   ebug\24.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\25.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates
>   \transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\26.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\27.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\a
>   ndroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\28.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\62.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormP
>   rojects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\63.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\64.jar --classpath_ent
>   ry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\65.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixe
>   r\debug\66.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\67.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermedia
>   tes\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\68.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\69.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platform
>   s\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\70.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\71.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\Websto
>   rmProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\72.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\73.jar --classpath_
>   entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\74.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesF
>   ixer\debug\75.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Users\Boogaloo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27\optional\org.apache.http.legacy.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:
>   \Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\resources.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\rt.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\jsse.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\li
>   b\jce.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\charsets.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\jfr.jar --min_sdk_version 19 --nodesugar_try_with_resources_if_needed --desugar_try_with_resources_omit_runtime
>   _classes}

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\test\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
(node:11324) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11324) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

**Original error:**

```
 :app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:108)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer$DefaultMethodFinder.visit(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:471)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.defaultMethodsDefined(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:319)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.visitEnd(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:88)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.InterfaceDesugaring.visitEnd(InterfaceDesugaring.java:85)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring.visitEnd(LambdaDesugaring.java:150)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:401)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:326)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:280)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:584)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:108)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer$DefaultMethodFinder.visit(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:471)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.defaultMethodsDefined(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:319)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.visitEnd(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:88)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.InterfaceDesugaring.visitEnd(InterfaceDesugaring.java:85)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring.visitEnd(LambdaDesugaring.java:150)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:401)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:326)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:280)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:584)

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with
 arguments {@C:\Users\Baron\WebstormProjects\IONIC\Projects\myApp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\tmp\desugar_args601386030457091935}

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
35 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 33 up-to-date
(node:13116) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:108)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer$DefaultMethodFinder.visit(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:471)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.defaultMethodsDefined(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:319)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.visitEnd(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:88)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.InterfaceDesugaring.visitEnd(InterfaceDesugaring.java:85)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring.visitEnd(LambdaDesugaring.java:150)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:401)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:326)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:280)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:584)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:108)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer$DefaultMethodFinder.visit(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:471)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.defaultMethodsDefined(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:319)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.visitEnd(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:88)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.InterfaceDesugaring.visitEnd(InterfaceDesugaring.java:85)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring.visitEnd(LambdaDesugaring.java:150)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:401)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:326)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:280)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:584)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with
 arguments {@C:\Users\Baron\WebstormProjects\IONIC\Projects\myApp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\tmp\desugar_args601386030457091935}

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
```

Comment: Did you try to invalidate caches? Whenever something weird happens, this should be the first thing you should try.

Comment: Will this still help even though the I'm using cordova?

Comment: It's possible, you only lose 2min of your time if you try it.

Comment: I tried it and it did not work, I still received the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that diffferent plugins had different dependencies of the same library.
To solve it I had to enable multi dex in the build.gradle file. 
The build.gradle file to make the change is located in platforms>android>app

```
android{

  defaultConfig{

    multiDexEnabled true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

go to \platforms\android\project.properties, replace PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION by “+” only like this :

before :

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:$PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION
```

after :

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+
```